# trying to get info on boto docs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am very new to python and looking into boto to do some quick list of SG.  My questions is when i look at the boto docs listed below...how do i know which attributes i can use.  For example in my sample output from python below, i create a variable called inst....first i used it to just get the instance id, next i used that to get the SG info....my question is .... how do i know what other attributes i can get?? maybe instance type, ami-id etc.. reading the doc below is a little bit confusing to me as i am new to python...any help/pointers would be appreciated...

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.instance

```
>>> reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
>>> for i in reservations:
     inst = i.instances[0]
     print inst

Instance:i-c8990c39
Instance:i-c7e45537
Instance:i-698047c1
>>>
>>> for i in reservations:
     inst = i.instances[0].groups
     print inst

[<boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0xf2c7d0>]
[<boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0xf2c350>]
[<boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0xf2c750>
 <boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0x10992d0>]
```

Also, how come i do not get the SG but I get the instance id??

```
>>> for i in reservations:
      inst = i.instances
      print inst

[Instance:i-c8990c39]
[Instance:i-c7e45537]
[Instance:i-698047c1] 

>>>
>>> for i in reservations:
      sg = i.groups
      print sg

[] [] []
>>>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the python built-in function dir:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

```
>>> reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
>>> instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
>>> dir(instance)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_in_monitoring_element', '_placement', '_previous_state', '_state', '_update', 'add_tag', 'ami_launch_index', 'architecture', 'block_device_mapping', 'client_token', 'confirm_product', 'connection', 'create_image', 'dns_name', 'ebs_optimized', 'endElement', 'eventsSet', 'get_attribute', 'get_console_output', 'group_name', 'groups', 'hypervisor', 'id', 'image_id', 'instance_profile', 'instance_type', 'interfaces', 'ip_address', 'item', 'kernel', 'key_name', 'launch_time', 'modify_attribute', 'monitor', 'monitored', 'monitoring', 'monitoring_state', 'persistent', 'placement', 'placement_group', 'placement_tenancy', 'platform', 'previous_state', 'previous_state_code', 'private_dns_name', 'private_ip_address', 'product_codes', 'public_dns_name', 'ramdisk', 'reason', 'reboot', 'region', 'remove_tag', 'requester_id', 'reset_attribute', 'root_device_name', 'root_device_type', 'sourceDestCheck', 'spot_instance_request_id', 'start', 'startElement', 'state', 'state_code', 'state_reason', 'stop', 'subnet_id', 'tags', 'terminate', 'unmonitor', 'update', 'use_ip', 'virtualization_type', 'vpc_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out the first Security Group id associated to your instance, you can do something like this:

```
>>> reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
>>>
>>> for i in reservations:
     sg = i.instances[0].groups[0]
     print sg.id


sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-1faxxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
sg-9f1xxxxx
```

> Okay I see what is going on, but another stupid question:
>   How come i do not get the SG but I get the instance id??

```
>>> for i in reservations:
      inst = i.instances
      print inst

[Instance:i-c8990c39]
[Instance:i-c7e45537]
[Instance:i-698047c1]
```

In this case you are printing all the reservations. Not the instances. Each reservation has one instance.

```
>>>
>>> for i in reservations:
      sg = i.groups
      print sg

[] [] []
>>>
>>>
```

In this case you are printing the security groups for the reservations. Reservations don't have security groups associated with them.

Comment: Okay i see what is going on, but another stupid question...how come i do not get the SG but i get the instance id??   >>> for i in reservations:
...     inst = i.instances
...     print inst
...
[Instance:i-c8990c39]
[Instance:i-c7e45537]
[Instance:i-698047c1]
>>>
>>> for i in reservations:
...    sg = i.groups
...    print sg
...
[]
[]
[]
>>>
>>>

Comment: @maxscalf check my answer. I added more details. This is basically another question in SO, so next time ask it as another question.

Answer (score 1):

The [EC2 instance reference](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.instance) you pointed us at *does* include the list of attributes e.g. image_id (for AMI id) and instance_type. Were you looking for something different?

Also, understand that when you 'print' an object, you will not necessarily see all of the attributes of that object - instead you will often see a simple string representation such as "Instance:i-c8990c39".

Finally, prepare to use dir(obj) frequently to find out more about the attributes of obj - Python documentation is rarely, if ever, complete and dir(obj) will help you. See [how to use type, str, and dir for introspection](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html).